# Embed Apache Calcite as a library in my application

Tags: embed, apache-calcite

Apache Calcite seems to have an interesting functionality of parsing SQL and connecting to multiple data sources including non-relational using adapters.

I see enough documentation on development of calcite itself but not for using it as a library in a third party application.

I would like to use Apache Calcite along with some of its adapters as a library in my application and use its functionality.

For example, Apache Drill uses calcite in its backend. Is it possible for a third party application to embed calcite and use its functionality? If yes, how do I go about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not understanding your question quite well.

Calcites power lies in its dedication on SQL optimisation, so sure you can use it.

are you talking about adding these into your 'maven' ?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
        <artifactId>calcite-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
        <artifactId>calcite-avatica</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```